# Lens phase mask on a laser beam profile in Fourier space

Tags: optics, computational-physics, fourier-transform, lenses

I have a Gaussian laser profile on which I want to apply a phase mask that acts like a lens. The phase mask is given by 
$$M_{lens} = \exp\left(-i\frac{k}{2f}(x^2 + y^2)\right)$$
where $x$ and $y$ are the transverse coordinates, $k = 2\pi/\lambda$, $\lambda$ is the wavelength, and $f$ is the focal length of the lens.

In normal space $(x,y)$, this can be done by direct multiplication of the phase mask with the beam profile $\psi$ as 
$$\psi \rightarrow \psi \cdot M_{lens}.$$

I do this operation numerically, thus both $\psi$ and $M_{lens}$ are discrete with some steps $\Delta x= \Delta y$ for simplicity. For some values of $k$ and $f$, the phase mask evolves too fast so I have to take very small values for $\Delta x$ in order to avoid any alias. This implies that, if I want to simulate a given area (say $1cm^2$), the matrix corresponding to $M_{lens}$ becomes huge, thus influencing the computational time.

So I thought that I could solve this problem as follows. I am solving the propagation of the beam using Fourier transform, so why not use it here also. I found that for the scenarios where the alias is present in the real space, in Fourier space this problem does not exist. So, I should take the Fourier of the product $\psi \cdot M_{lens}$, and it should work fine. And here is the problem.

The Fourier of this product is the convolution of their Fourier transforms. I compute the FFTs of $\psi$ and $M_{lens}$ and apply the convolution using SciPy (Python library). In order to check the result, I transform the convolution with iFFT and look at the amplitude profile. I expect that the phase should be a mess in real space (because of the alias problem), but the amplitude should still be the Gaussian of interest. It is not, and I am not sure why.

Is this approach correct or am I missing something?

Note: I am interested in the reasoning, not the computational part. I mentioned SciPy only as extra info for what I have used.

Comment: Because the system is radially symmetric, you should be able to transform to r, theta coordinates to convert to a one-dimensional problem and thereby greatly reduce the amount of computation required.

Comment: This is true, however I have presented a simplified version of what I am actually doing, with an emphasis on the problem. In the general case that interests me the radial symmetry is not valid. Thanks for the feedback.